# Setting a website server with mailing service

Tags: php, email, server

I have this job creating a simple website for someone, a website that
should be able to send mails to any email address, and I'm having some trouble 
making it happen.

I'm using a simple free file server (cuccfree), but I don't have access to the server itself, only to upload files to the htdocs folder. I also configured a mail address in my server, but mailing only work to the server's email address (When ever I ask the php file on server to send the mail to Gmail/Yahoo and such, it does not work).

I've searched Google for an answer but kinda got lost..

I'd really like some help about this:

1. I'm ready to switch to a better file server service (whether it's free or not) that can support configuring mailing service that would work, and would be glad to hear some suggestions for one.
2. I'd also love to be guided of how to configure the mailing service on that server.
3. Also, when thinking about this, there's a good chance that my server's mails are being blocked by Gmail/Yahoo and such, otherwise anyone could have just set a mail server and send as much mails as they want.. so is that possible that this is my problem? is there any way to solve this and kind of confirm with the mailing companies that I'm a legit website?

I'm really not familiar enough with this topic' and would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sending emails from a php file using **mail()** function?

Comment: Yea, thinks there's a problem there?

Comment: Rightly sending emails is not a simple task, I would recommend you to use specialized services like MailChimp, SendGrid or other to do the email sending part.